# Extract dataframes from python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

I have a python dictionary containing 3 dataframes and nothing else. I need to call each dataframe by dataframe name without using d['']; for example, with the dataframe loopdata1, I need to call it without doing d['loopdata1']. Here's the dictionary with the 3 dataframes loopdata1, loopdata2, and loopdata3:

```
dict_items([('loopdata1',    index       id        name  age  sex  sterilized
0      0  A006100       Scamp  120    0           1
1      1  A047759        Oreo  120    0           1
2      2  A134067      Bandit  192    0           1
3      3  A141142      Bettie  180    1           1
4      4  A163459       Sasha  180    1           0
5      5  A165752         Pep  180    0           1
6      6  A178569        Boti  180    0           1
7      7  A189592     Ophelia  216    1           1
8      8  A191351     Bri-Bri  192    1           0
9      9  A197810  Sassafrass  168    1           1), 
('loopdata2',    index       id     name  age  sex  sterilized
0      0  A200922   Carlos  192    0           1
1      1  A208755  Kootrie  168    0           1
2      2  A210457    Caleb  204    0           1
3      3  A212672     Cujo  156    1           0
4      4  A214991   Prissy  228    1           1
5      5  A215368  Guiness  156    0           1
6      6  A218622   Oliver  180    0           1
7      7  A218624   Cookie  180    0           1
8      8  A221174    Lippy  216    1           1
9      9  A221327    Jamie  192    1           1), 
('loopdata3',    index       id    name  age  sex  sterilized
0      0  A249087  *Polly  180    1           1
1      1  A251095  Beauty  168    1           1
2      2  A251214     Rex  144    0           1
3      3  A251268   Sully  204    0           1
4      4  A251402     Amy  216    1           1
5      5  A253939   Dirty  144    1           1
6      6  A254503   Daisy  204    1           1
7      7  A256412    Beau  192    0           0
8      8  A258441  Spring  168    1           1
9      9  A260631   Popki  168    0           1)])
```

Here's the code that generated the dictionary -- I'm importing excel files that have the same names as the dataframes and stripping off the '.xlsx':

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
my_dir = '../test/'

os.chdir( my_dir )
filelist = []

for files in glob.glob( '*.xlsx' ) :
    filelist.append(files)

lst = [os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in filelist]
lst

d = {}
for dfname in lst:
    d[dfname] = pd.read_excel(dfname + '.xlsx')
```

I've tried [Convert a dictionary to a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466639/convert-a-dictionary-to-a-pandas-dataframe) and [Extracting dataframes from a dictionary of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933044/extracting-dataframes-from-a-dictionary-of-dataframes) with no luck. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: This so sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: You can directly access a list of values of a dict with `list(dict.values())` and index into it

Comment: How can I clarify Scott?

Comment: Thanks Anderson, that's useful but I'm trying to call the entire dataframe, as in newdf = loopdata1, instead of doing newdf = d['loopdata1'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could append incoming dataframes together instead of adding them to a dict.
    `first = True
    for dfname in lst:
        if first = True:
            main_df = pd.read_excel(dfname + '.xlsx')
            first = False
        else:
            appending_df = pd.read_excel(dfname + '.xlsx')
            main.df = main_df.append(appending_df)`

Comment: Thanks Zack, I can work with that! Only thing is, the last line should be: main_df = main_df.append(appending_df)

Comment: nice catch, I made the change to reflect