# Extract dataframe from dictionary by name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have made a loop where I iterate over (csv) files in a folder, read them into a dictionary of dataframes and name them after the csv file (e.g. file1.csv becomes file1_df). I do some work on the data and generate new rows, then I try to subset part of my dataframes into a new dataframe (file1_df2). I would like to later reference these dataframes outside of the dictionary.

```py
    df_dict = {}
    for file in os.listdir(datadir):  # Loop over the files in that folder (only has CSV files)
        df_name = file[:-4] + '_df'  # Trim off .csv to name the dataframe
        df_dict[df_name] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(datadir, file))
```

Is it possible to reference these dataframes by name? So later I can just call `file1_df2` instead of `df_dict["file1_df2"]`?

In essence I am asking the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933044/extracting-dataframes-from-a-dictionary-of-dataframes). It doesn't look like he got this answered either, so I think this might not be possible, but I have yet to find an answer that explicitly says it isn't.

---

I know this is possible in languages like SAS and Stata, but I have never figured out how to do it in Python. In those languages, you can plug your placeholder variable directly into the name of something.

```
/* In SAS */
%let param = test1
libname path "C:\User\&param."

proc sql;
create &param._df as 
select * from path.&param.
quit;
```

```
/* In Stata */
foreach i in file1 file2 {
    import delimited "`i'.csv", clear
    save "`i'.dta", replace
}
```

etc. If this is **not** possible, I would like to know that with certainty. Thank you!

Comment: it is possible but not a good idea , check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6181959/11220780

Comment: Possible - yes see e.g. ```exec``` function: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#exec Recommended - rather not - because how will you know programatically, which names exist, and which don't.

Comment: Knowing it is possible and not recommended (and why it is not recommended) is also great information. Thank you for the resources.

Answer (score 3):

The lack of answers is likely because nobody can really tell WHY you want to do this. The question seems to stem from applying an SAS / Stata workflow to python that just doesn't make any sense.

However, i *think* this does what you're asking

```py
import pandas as pd
my_csvs = ["name1.csv", "name2.csv", "name3.csv"]
my_dfs = [pd.read_csv(csv) for csv in my_csvs]
df_dict = {name.replace(".csv", "_df"): df for name, df in zip(my_csvs, my_dfs)}

# access dataframes with (advisable to use this method!)
csv2 = df_dict["name2_df"]
```

Then, we can add these keys to our name space with an `exec()` call:

```py
# now add them to the namespace
for k in df_dict.keys():
    exec(f"{k} = df_dict['{k}']")
    # or use "{k} = df_dict['{k}']".format(k=k) for python < 3.5?

# Now does this work?
print(name2_df)
```

And this actually does work. However, any IDE is going to flag the last line, because it doesn't seem like you've declared that variable.

### I strongly advise against using this.

Comment: I was about to post something like that. The beauty on it is that Python just create a reference and not a new object, and that is easily checked using ```csv2 is df_dict['name2_df']```.

Comment: Thank you, knowing that it is possible but not recommended is also very helpful.